# Entity Framework relationships on no related tables

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-6, foreign-key-relationship

I have three tables in a non-relational database:

[image]

`roles_users` is a lookup table that holds the identity fields for both `users` and `roles`

In my code, I've created the necessary entity classes for all three of these tables:

the `users`

```
[Table("users")]
public class User
    : AuditableEntity<int>
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "Id")]        
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    [Required]
    public string login { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    [Required]
    public string name { get; set; }       

    **public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRole { get; set; }**
}
```

and `roles`

```
[Table("roles")]
public class Role
    : Entity<int>
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "Id")]        
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Role")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    **public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRole { get; set; }**
}
```

and `roles_users`

```
[Table("roles_users")]
public class UserRole
    : Entity<int>
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Role")]
    public int role_id { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int user_id { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to bring the roles table to the users table so I can retrieve the associated role for the user, and from what I've read, the `ForeignKey` should be placed on the `role_id` and `user_id` on the class UserRoles (roles_users) mapping the two tables together, as per the code posted above, but this does not work.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**

I'm not using Visual Studio to generate these entity classes, and don't want to.

**Update 2**

I'm now getting the following error on multiplicity

> UserRole_Role_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role
>   'UserRole_Role_Source' in relationship 'UserRole_Role'. Because the
>   Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound
>   of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.

**Update 3**

I figured it out, the multiplicity on `UserRole` in both `User` and `Role` should be a collection, as it's a many-to-many relationship, even though it's not, so I changed the code as per the highlighted blocks in the code above.

Answer (score 1):

You designed it as a many-to-many relationship.

If you do not want it to be a many-to-many relationship then you may drop the joint table and add the role_id column as a foreign key of roles directly on users table. You still need a Collection for UserID on class Role anyway.

If your users can have only one role at a time, then the joint table is over-engineering.

Comment: hi, thanks, unfortunately this is managed by a third party and we have no permissions to change the tables. i fully agree that this is an over-engineered schema, sadly, we have no permission, and no budget to change :(

Comment: It may prove the right choice if requirements on this are subject to change and also because most ready to use ACL plugins will support it out-of-the-box anyway.

Comment: we are pushing for a re-engineering of the database in MS Sql as it's currently in MySql (budget constraints, and a third party built it). Thanks for the hint will go this way eventually if quote is signed off

Comment: PostgreSQL is usually a better choice than MySQL and it is also free. I am not aware of any MSSQL advantages over PostgreSQL.

Comment: Interesting, thank you, I will start looking into this if it turns out sufficient for our purpose, I'll propose this in our next meeting with the client. again, thank you

Comment: If MSSQL is sufficient for your purposes than PostgreSQL certainly is, it is the opposite that may not be true.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71389/discussion-between-lnrdo-and-jadederic).